# Create a Java class With a variable(arrayList) of the same class

Tags: java, class, arraylist

Hello I would like to create a Class which contains an array with the same class.

I tried with the code specified below, but the array i created has been infinite.

```
public class State {

private String Valor1;
private String Valor2;
private ArrayList arrayStatesAnteriores;

}
```

And i did the set and get with the refactor of netbeans

`state.setArrayStatesAnteriores(arrayStateAnteriores);`

But i have the problem of array being infinite. Any idea?

Comment: _But i have the problem the array is infinite Any idea?_ please expand

Comment: We'll need more information to help.

Comment: So basically you want a list of states which could be of any size?

Comment: Sounds like his constructor creates an instance of the same class, and is hence recursive, triggering a stack overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the way **I understand it**: You have a class that represents a program's state in a given moment, and you want to keep a list of the state that the program has had, that's why you say it's an infinite list.

First the `State` class, which has two fields `value1` and `value2` one constructor which sets the two fields to the passed values:

```
public class State {

    /**
     * This is the constructor 
    */
    public State(String value1, String value2){
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.value2 = value2;
    }

    // Omiting getters/setters for brevety.
    // This will be set by the constructor using the values that it
    // receives as arguments 
    // e.g
    // new State("My Val1","My Val2");
    private String value1;
    private String value2;
}
```

Then this class would be contained in an array of `States`

```
List<State> states =  new ArrayList<States>();
```

Then you would use this classes in your main or other classes:

```
import State;
public class Program {

    // This array holds the states that the program has had.
    private static List<State> states =  new ArrayList<State>();
    public static void main(String[] args){
        // ...
        // Do something
        // ...

        // Save the states
        states.add(new State("State 1","Value 1"))
        // Save another state
        states.add(new State("State 2","Value 2"))
        // The arraylist  now contains two states of the program.
    }

}
```

Hope it helps feel free to ask more questions.

Comment: Sorry I dont know very well java and I dont have clear the poing When I have my class with variables like this


 public class State {
 private String value1;
     private String value2;
 List<State> states =  new ArrayList<States>();

 public State(String value1, String value2){
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.value2 = value2;}
 }

Answer (score 2):

Use a `List`, and **initialize** it:

```
public class State {
  private List<State> statesAnteriores = new ArrayList<State>();
}
```

Comment: You can't instantiate List, did you mean ArrayList?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, just a few tweeks on your code:

- ArrayList is just in implementation of the List interface. You don't have to use it when defining a member field.
- you should define the type of the list elements, see generics in Java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

so that would be

```
public class State {

    private String Valor1;
    private String Valor2;
    private List<State> arrayStatesAnteriores;



}
```

And regarding your question, what do you mean by " the array is infinite"?
You mean it is `null` after you have set it?

```
state.setArrayStatesAnteriores(arrayStateAnteriores);
```

the reason for this may be you setting the value of the list with itself, which is null.

try something like this:

```
state.setArrayStatesAnteriores(new ArrayList<State>());
```

Comment: When i Debug the code I have somethin like that:  State : araryState state...arrayState....array... ArrayState. im going to try with list :D thanks

Comment: When I debug the code is like  
State
-Value 1
-Array States[0]State
  -Value 1
  -Array States[0]]State
    -Value 1
    -Array States[0]
            States[1]
                         States[2]

         States[1]State
    -Value 1
    -Array States[0]
            States[1]
                         States[2]
         States[2]State
    -Value 1
    -Array States[0]
            States[1]
                         States[2]

         States[1]State
    -Value 1
    -Array States[0]
            States[1]
                         States[2]